# How to disable the link MissingFile on Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I have some personal photos which are encrypted by CryptKeeper. I doesn't like to disclose them to anyone. Whenever i lke to view them, I mount them using CryptKeeper. I need to include these photos in Shotwell photo manager at the time of mounting. So, I mounted them using CryptKeeper. Then I imported them to Shotwell. I made a new event and etc to organize and view those photos. After that I unmounted them using CryptKeeper because someone may see it. Now I don't want any single trail on Shotwell beacuse of the same problem. But there is a new button 'MissingFiles' appeared and when i clicked on it, all the photo thumbnail which i unmounted showed there. I dont't want right'click on them and select 'remove from library'; beacuse when i want to view them next time on Shotwell, I need to import, organize, etc at that time. So, the only option here is to disable the unavailability of that MisssingFiles button.

Comment: Simply remove them from your library prior to unmounting with Cryptkeeper. Highlight the 'personal photos' then Shift + Del.

Comment: To be clear, Shotwell keeps a thumbnail of every photo in your collection in ~/.cache/shotwell.  So even if you were to hide the Missing Photos item in the sidebar, someone could still find the thumbnails if they were so inclined.

Comment: @eric-yorba There is a way of keeping a totally private `shotwell` database and cache- see my script at the end of my answer. The secret is to temporarily export `XDG_CACHE_HOME` in the wrapper script as well as using Shotwell's `-d` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Shotwell you could use an ***alternative library*** for your 'secret' pictures, which would also leave the default `.shotwell` folder in your home folder intact. You would only need to remove `shotwell.log` in `~/.cache/shotwell` to eliminate evidence that this different library had been opened. It is safe to remove this log file as it is generated automatically whenever `shotwell` is run. This log file is all I have in `.cache` after using `Shotwell`, just one file and no other thumbnail database (even with display hidden files on).

Using `cryptkeeper`, I wish to store the secret `shotwell` library in my encrypted folder, so I mount my encrypted folder (called `secret`) and point `shotwell` towards that folder when I launch it:

```
shotwell -d /home/mike/misc/secret
```

Now I import my pictures from my encrypted folder and the library will stay in my encrypted folder. This is the standard command that lets you select an ***alternative library*** location for `shotwell`, while retaining the default one unaltered. Each time you load up your encrypted folder and run the `shotwell` command your library will be ready to use. Now if you do it this way everytime, there will be no *missing file* warnings.

Now when you unmount your `cryptkeeper` folder you can run `shotwell` again as normal and it will load your default library (just see my note above about removing the `shotwell` log if you want to cover your tracks).

**NOTE**: for `Shotwell 0.13` and above, you will have to launch the program with a bash wrapper script when using it with `cryptkeeper` or `truecrypt`, as the `.cache` thumbnail folder needs also to be kept private. So, something like this should launch `Shotwell`- point the cache and `shotwell` to your encrypted folder or volume:

```
#!/bin/bash
export XDG_CACHE_HOME=/media/truecrypt6/shotwell
shotwell -d /media/truecrypt6/shotwell
```